Flight search engine for German Rail&Fly tickets (QYG)
I recently found out that some airlines (Latam, Condor, maybe more?) allow to book tickets to or from QYG. Which is a code for German rail stations. Those tickets can be used in any high-speed train going to the airport, making the trip much more convenient. Sometimes they cost the same as a regular flight ticket. However, I can't seem to find this code in any search engine (Google Flights, Kayak, Skyscanner).
Does anyone know if there's any search engine working with this code?

I doubt it. IMO, the only way to implement it in a way that does not give useless results (e.g. you don't want the search engine to search for trains to Cologne when your destination is Dresden) is to set it to "all airports in Germany" and not search for trains at all - and unless you live in a central location in Germany, this is often not wanted, because not many people are willing to travel to "the other end of Germany" only to get to the airport.

@Sabine QYG is a code for 'any German train station'. It does not matter if you want to go to Cologne or Dresden. The way it works is, that you buy your QYG ticket from the airline and then you "check in' online for your train and not until there, you have to specify exactly which train station you are travelling to or from. Then you get a train ticket for the specified route.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo Yes, I understand what QYG stands for, but what would a search engine search for if I tell it I want to go to "any train station"? It certainly shouldn't search for a flight+train to a random train station as that will most likely not be the train station I want to go to. So at best, it can search for a flight to any airport in Germany, and as I mentioned, I don't think many people are interested in such a search (but maybe I'm wrong and it's just me who doesn't like to spend 8 hours on a train because the flight from/to that other airport is 50-100€ cheaper).
